# How to have different $_POST value based on different button clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I have following php:

```
if (!empty($text_arr)) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($text_arr as $key => $twt) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo '<form action="'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'" method="POST">';
        echo $twt['text'];
        echo ' <input type="submit" value="Publish" />';
        echo ' <input type="hidden" name="id_str" value="'. $twt['id_str'] .'" />';
        echo "</form>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
print_r($_POST);
```

As you can see I've submit button that publishes post. There are many entries and each entry is a form. So that I get correct id_str in $_POST.

I don't like the fact that I have multiple forms for each option. Is there a cleaner way to do this?? and have only 1 form? I don't want to use ajax or js.

p.s. I'm hangover, it is possible I don't see something evident. Or simply asking dumb questions. Please be patient. Hope my post makes at least little sense.

**Thanks to nandhp I came up with solution:**

```
if (!empty($text_arr)) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo '<form action="'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'" method="POST">';
    foreach ($text_arr as $key => $twt) {
        echo "<li>";
            echo $twt['text'];
            echo ' <button type="submit" name="id_str" value="'. $twt['id_str'] .'" >Publish</button>';
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: there is noway to do that

Comment: I don't understand the question. But the guy above me is wrong. There is always a way to do it. It just might suck.

Comment: @Jhawins I was aware of that risk when I posted.

Comment: I just don't get what you're asking. At all. I see 1 form.

Comment: @Jhawins its a loop...

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing, you're doing it terribly wrong. Rethink this from the core and find a different, sensible approach.

Comment: @Jhawins nandhps answer works perfectly. It seems my question was not so bad after all.

Comment: You really were trying to program hung over, and you expect SO to bail you out?

Comment: @Kazark where did that come from? Attitude problems? My question is legitimate, no matter if I'm hungover drunk or dead...

Comment: I've written some of my best code when drunk. Difficult to modify later though - "What the hell did I do there?" ;)

Comment: @PeteR ;) yep, that happens :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need it to be `$_POST['id_str']`, you can set a unique `name` attribute on each submit button:

```
<input type=submit name=submit0001 value="Publish">
```

Then you can tell which button was pressed by looking at `$_POST['submit0001']`, `$_POST['submit0002']`, and so forth, to see which one was clicked.

Comment: Hey thanks for direction. I came up with a better solution, without need to have value inside $_POST key: <button type="submit" name="id_str" value="'. $twt['id_str'] .'" >Publish</button>